# Generalizing the drunken man's walk for better programming?

Tags: combinatorics, programming

So I am working on a problem which I believe I have figured out to be able to implement it through programming but I think this can be better done by first generalizing the problem properly.

The problem is given as:

Alex is very sad after finding out that he is responsible for John's death. He tries to drown his sorrows in alcohol and gets very drunk. Now he wants to return home but is unable to walk straight. For every 3 steps forward, he ends up walking one step backward.
Formally, in the 1st second he moves 3 steps forward, in the 2nd second he moves 1 step backwards, in the 3rd second he moves 3 steps forward, in 4th second 1 step backwards, and so on.
How far from his initial position will Alex be after k seconds have passed? Assume that Alex 's initial position is 0.

Input Format
The first line of input contains a single integer T denoting the number of test cases. The description of T test cases follows.
The first line of each test case contains a single integer k, the number of seconds after which Alex's position is to be calculated.

Output Format
For each test case, output a single line containing one integer - Alex 's position after k seconds.

Constraints
1≤T≤100000
0≤k≤100000
The sum of k over all test cases does not exceed 1000000

Sample Input 1
3
5
11
23

Sample Output 1
7
13
25

Explanation
1st Test Case

Alex walks 3 steps forward in the 1st second, ending up at 3
Alex walks 1 step backward in the 2nd second, ending up at 2
Alex walks 3 steps forward in the 3rd second, ending up at 5
Alex walks 1 step backward in the 4th second, ending up at 4
Alex walks 3 steps forward in the 5th second, ending up at 7
'''

My solution is:

```
time=input="Enter the seconds passed: "
if time%2==1:
    steps=time+2
    print(steps)
if time%2==0:
    steps=time
    print(steps)
```

Is there a better way to generalize and thus solve the problem?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this...

Comment: I actually want to see the mathematical perspective on this, like what is the generalized solution of this problem?, and the process of doing it. I am not good at combinatorics sorry.

Comment: You have found a reasonable expression for distance after an odd or even number of seconds: $k+2$ and $k$ respectively.  You could combine these into $k+1-(-1)^k$ for non-negative integer $k$ but it would not add much information and still would be wrong for non-integer $k$

Comment: @Henry oh i see, if there were lets say no formal way of walking i.e he could either walk forward or backwards, how would that change the problem? assuming he still had to walk 3 steps if he were to walk forward and walk 1 step if he were to walk backwards.